# Sizing panels in an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf

I have a parent view model, that contains a collection of other view models (of same type) (children). On Initialization the number of children will be decided (varying).

The child View consists of a button and a list box. Initially the listbox is hidden. On click of button the list box appears and on clicking outside (outside of the control or any other child button).

On init only buttons will be shown. I want these buttons to be spaced across the available width. The requirement is that once the button is clicked (when listbox is shown) the width of the whole child will increase (lets say 350) and when it is hidden it reverts back to the original size.

In the parent i am using a ItemsControl to show the children views. I have tried all controls but not able to figure ou a appropriate solution for this. I have two issues:

1. On Button click i am able to show current listbox. If i click another button teh first one goes off. Till here it works fine. But i also need that the currentopen listbox closes on click anywhere outside of the control (child control)
2. How to automatically size and resize based on what is clicked . First all should be propotionately sized and then when one is clicked it's size increases (here other childs resize with the rest available space). When the one (open control) is collapsed, all of them come back to normal proptionate sizes.

Any ideas ?

BTW, i am using MVVM pattern for this.

Comment: This is not clear.  What does "and on clicking outside .." mean?

Comment: Outside means outside of the current open pannel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using a flag to direct the view to perform calc and refresh/readjust the sizing as when needed.

like on-click routine, set the flag on
whenever the view (pre-)painting/drawing event is kicked in, check if the flag is on, do the calc and sizing, then off the flag.

Comment: I am not sure what you are referiing. My first question is that what control should i use in the items control. Is it stack/wrap/Uniformgrid/grid control ? The control that i use should in no case go outside of the main window. Currently whatever i am using, it goes outside of window if no of pannels are more and one is selected (which makes it's width more)

Comment: if your child controls keep moving out the container, looks to me the issue is with the container, try anohter contrainer.

Comment: What container, i have tried everything as mentioned above. The parent control uses a grid which contains a items control